When does apt install packages manual?
When I downgrade packages using command sudo apt install <pkg>/<target-release> <pkg>/<target-release> ... it seems to retain auto/manual state of the packages. Usually when I explicitly tell packages to install, it will make packages manually installed. What is the logic?

Upgrades and downgrades don’t change a package’s automatic or manual installation flag; this includes upgrades or downgrades forced by explicitly mentioning a package with apt install. As far as I can tell, that’s the logic.
The state is set to manual if a package is initially installed and explicitly named, as you’d expect. It is also set to manual if a package installation is requested and the package is already installed, in the requested version, unless re-installation has been requested, or “only upgrades”. This allows apt install to be used as a shorthand for apt-mark manual, but it can be surprising. apt does at least tell you that it is marking the package as manually installed.
